# Bounding box only for the visible part of the layer

Tags: openlayers-3

I was wondering if there is a way to get the bounding box of not the complete layer, but only the part of the layer that is visible in the current zoom level of the map?

So, I need to get the screen coordinates of the bounding box of the layer drawn on the screen. I could not find a way to achieve this.

EDIT:

Unfortunately this is not solving my problem. This is exactly the point that I got to latest and in some cases it is not working. Since stackoverflow does not allow me to upload images because of my reputation I will try to describe:
Imagine that I have a path which is crossing the screen almost parallel to y axis, however outside the screen it is at least x-axis long. In this case the solution proposed will return min and max screen coordinates for x axis, where it needs to be a short interval that it is crossing the screen. In a way I need the bounding box of the visible part of the layer.

EDIT 2: 
Thank you all for your answers. I tried to use "getFeaturesInExtent" function, but I get an error saying: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". I am using the latest OpenLayers which is version 3.4.0. I suppose I am getting this error because this function is not implemented in this version. 
The way I am using is the following:

```
var mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var features = result.getSource().getFeaturesInExtent(mapExtent);
```

What kind of solution do you suggest for me? (I tried to use master version downloading ZIP from: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3, but the map did not work in this case.) 
Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but [`ol.source.Vector#getFeaturesInExtent`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeaturesInExtent) called with the map extent gives you all visible features. Then you could calculate the real extent with these features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the following:

```
    var mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

    var intersectedFeatures = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
      if(ol.extent.containsCoordinate(mapExtent, points[i]))
        intersectedFeatures.push(points[i]);
    }

    var visibleLayerExtent = ol.extent.boundingExtent(intersectedFeatures);
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only things what you need is the extent of the view and the extent of the layer and the ol.extent.getIntersection() Function.

You can get the Extent of the current View by f.ex

```
map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

The global extent of your layer by

```
`layer.getExtent()`.
```

And the intersecting Extent with.

```
ol.extent.getIntersection(extent1, extent2,opt_extent)
```

Should return the intersecting extent of the current view and your layer. Be aware that not all mentioned functions are stable.

Comment: The probelm is (related to the basicallay correct answer of tsauerwein) that the vector feature extent methods are intersecting with an given extent, but they are returning the extent of the whole feature geometry. So i think you would get an bounding box back which is bigger than the view, when the feature geometry is overlapping with the non-view area. My suggestion would be to get all featuresInExtent (viewExtent) like tsauerwein recommended it and use the extent of this features instead of the layer.getExtent() of my last answer. Please let me know how you solved your probelm at the end.